# Modifying list to order with date inside View

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have this jquery function to rearrange list based on datetime when the user click sort link

```
 $('#sort-date-added').click(function () {
            '@Model.HomeProducts' = '@Model.HomeProducts.OrderBy(x => x.LastModifiedDate)';
            alert('xx');
        $.each('@Model.HomeProducts', function (index) {
            alert('@Model.HomeProducts.ElementAt(index).Name');
            //x++;
        });
  });
```

This is the sort link

```
<p><a id="sort-date-added" href="#">Sort by Date Added</a></p>
```

but it doesn't work, does anyone know why, can anyone help in this solution or better solution ?

Comment: $.each('@Model.HomeProducts', function (key, index) { } ?

Comment: what is the key represent ?

Comment: @BrianMains I am holding the list ordered alphabetically and at the run time if the user clicked on sort by date I will change the sort to be ordered by time, that line will order them by date

Answer (score 0):

If i were you, i would do the following:

Main View:

```
<p><a id="sort-date-added" href="#">Sort by Date Added</a></p>
<div id="list">
    @Html.Partial("_ProductsList", Model)
</div>
```

Partial View "_ProductsList":

```
<ul>
@foreach(var item in Model.HomeProducts)
{
   <li>@item.Name</li>
}
</ul>
```

Js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     var ajaxOrderByDate = $.post(
                            'Home/GetOrderedProducts/', { 
                                 orderType: 1
                            });

     $('#sort-date-added').on('click', function () {
          ajaxOrderByDate.done(function(data){
                            $('#list').html(data);
                         })
                         .fail(function(){
                            console.log("error");
                         });
     }

});
```

ASP.NET in HomeController or whatever:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetOrderedProducts(int orderType)
{
     switch(orderType)
     {
          case 1:
            //order by date
     }

     return PartialView("_ProductsList", Model);
}
```

You could make an enum for the fields you are ordering by.

Basically the idea is to create a partial view containing the list, and order the elements of this list on the server. You update the view by rerendering just the list via ajax.
I think this is the best approach.